# Solving Bilevel Optimization with Nonlinear Subproblem

Tags: optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to implement a bilevel optimization program using Python-based package for Adversarial Optimization (PAO), which is based on Pyomo. Here I have a mixed-integer master problem and two subproblems each with a non-linear constraint.

However, in the `pao` documentation I could not find any help how to solve this model. There only seems to be examples of linear subproblems.

Has anyone done this yet, and if so, is there any documentation on it?

Comment: There's not whatsoever enough to answer here. Either you need to add code and more concrete detail here, or add more theoretical detail and move to Operations Research.

Comment: There certainly is information about solver capabilities: [PAO/Solvers](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solvers.html) It seems that any available solver can solve a general non-linear problem, but a bilinear. Also, you can try to use PAO to model and reformulate -check [reformulations](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xfrm.html)- your problem and solve it with `mindtpy` or other solver